# Delphi Tokyo FMX - TDateEdit not changing displayed month

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am running Delphi 10.2 Tokyo with the April hotfix applied on Windows 10 (I do not have Creator's update installed). I am noticing a weird behavior with the TDateEdit control:

Here's what the date drop down looks like when first opened (showing current date):

[image: Default date shown]

However, when I change the month or year by either using the left/right arrow or by clicking on the month/year and picking a new value, the month does not get redrawn and continues to show the month of June:

[image: Month is not redrawn to reflect July]

I do not have any event handlers on the date edit. I am not sure what may be causing this. Any ideas what may be causing this behavior - or what I could do to fix it?

**UPDATE 20170613:** As this seems to be a bug, I have opened a ticket with Embarcadero: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18348

**UPDATE 20170816:** A workaround has been posted to https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18348 by Matt Davis that seems to work for now (until Embarcadero issues a proper fix).

Comment: There were some issues regarding date time picker control, but on the MS side. As a solution was adding a specific application manifest. Maybe it's related to this issue as well. This one for example [RSP-17886](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17886) (see the discussion).

Comment: Thanks @Victoria. I had searched for this issue and thought it was related to the Windows Creators update. Could you please point me to some guidance related to the change I need to make to the application manifest? I would be happy to give that a try...

Comment: There it is [Adding the Custom Manifest File to Your Application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Customizing_the_Windows_Application_Manifest_File#Adding_the_Custom_Manifest_File_to_Your_Application).

Comment: Thanks, @Victoria - very helpful. I tried the custom manifest file, but that does not seem to resolve the issue I have outlined :(

Comment: A `TDateEdit` is a FireMonkey control, just as a reminder. I might be wrong, but I don't think it got anything to do with Windows Common controls and is entirely self-drawn by the FMX framework.

Comment: Moreover, I can reproduce this on "10 Seattle". It also applies to changing days and year with the keyboard. It looks like a bug.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful - thanks for validating the issue :) I remember this working a couple of months back - not sure what happened in the meantime. Not sure if the April hotfix messed it up... To validate this, I created a simple project in 10.1.2 Berlin - and the date edit works perfectly. So maybe this is a bug with the april hotfix?

Comment: I have logged an issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18348. In the meantime, if anyone has any way to work around this, please let me know. Also - let me know if there is a way to roll back the April hotfix without having to reinstall Tokyo all over again.

Comment: @Rohit: I didn't install the hotfix yet, but generally, they tell you to backup or move or rename the files that are being fixed. Did they say so and did you do that?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis As far as I recall, there was no notification to back up, move or rename the files. I unfortunately do not have a backup...

Comment: @Rohit: Ok, then try a repair, although I am not sure if that works. Or export all settings (using the -- rather new -- tool for that) and re-install anyway. Probably no need to re-install all components/plugins/experts/etc, because you can re-import the settings. Better to get over with it than to waste lots of time trying to find a way to avoid reinstalling.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - I agree with you and much as I hated doing it, I went ahead and did an uninstall and then a re-install. Now my projects won't open with an error of Delphi.Personality is not available. Quite frustrating :(

Comment: Finally got thru the whole reinstall of Tokyo (plus all the getit packages, etc). No hotfix applied. The issue I outlined still persists (so it can't be related to the hotfix - unless the hotfix affected DLL files in System). Can anyone else replicate this issue with Tokyo?